# Project architectures differences for Django + Vuejs (or other) integration

Tags: django, vue.js, architecture

I'm currently looking at project setups for a Django + Vuejs project (though I guess the question is likely just as valid for other frontends, react, svelte etc.).

It seems that there are mainly 2 approaches that come up often, resulting in the following project structure:

The frontend embedded within the Django project (perhaps as a git submodule):

```
root
├── djangoapp
├── djangoproject
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
├── venv
└── vueproject
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package.json
    ├── public
    └── src
```

Another approach is to have them at the same level from project root, as 2 seperate projects actually (or I guess both could be git submodules to a "wrapper" project), so essentially:

```
root
├── djangoproject
│   └── <django files & folders>
└── vueproject
    └── <vue files & folders>
```

With the 2nd approach, it seems you basically just see Django as an API. Stuff like collectstatic does not (?) come into play. In development, you need a server up to serve Django's api, and a dev server for the vue frontend.

With the 1st approach (if I understand correctly), seems that you build the Vue static files, and then manage all of that with Django's collectstatic/static files management.

Seems the 2nd approach is a better decoupling of the 2 components. With the 1st, you need to configure vue (or vite) rather specifically and Django's static files as well. What we gain by doing this isn't obvious to me - the more I think about it, the more it seems clear that the 2nd approach is better.

What potential advantages would there be in the 1st approach? Dev conveniences I'm not seeing? Easier deployment? Or is it just a somewhat outdate approach that still lingers the web?